# Django CMS Placeholder: Plugin Blacklist

Tags: django, django-cms

Once I create a custom plugin it's available for every `placeholder` on the site. What if I want them only avaliable on a specific `static_placeholder` and excluded from the rest?

I know the [documentation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/3.1/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf) tells me how to manually include every plugin on each placeholder but not how to exclude a plugin from it. Is it currently possible?

I'm working on Django CMS 3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can only whitelist plugins, not blacklist them. This means that for now, you have to specify the list of all plugins (except your custom plugin) on all other placeholders (note you can select all placeholders in a template by using the template as key), and define the list for your static placeholder that includes your custom plugin.

It might also be worth it to raise this on the [django CMS Issue Tracker](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/new) to maybe find a better solution in future versions.

Comment: Thank you. In case of future followups: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4979

Answer (score 1):

A follow-up on ojii's answer:

Although it's currently being approved for merge (see [#5412](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/5412)), the method described by yakky will be as follows:

> To implement blacklist, add the plugin to be blacklisted in `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF[None]['excluded_plugins']` list

See [#4979](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4979)

Thank you @yakky :)

**EDIT**: More information pulled from [Issue #5412](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/5412):

> Sometimes a global configuration would make things much nicer /
>   simpler
>
> @ojii suggested a for level structure like (in increasing
>   order of precedence)
>
> `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF[None] (global)`
>
> `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF['template']` (if template is given)
>
> `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF['placeholder']`
>
> `CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF['template placeholder']` (if template is given)

**EDIT 2** Tried these new configurations on Django CMS 3.4.0 and it worked flawlessly

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'About': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['CMSArticlePlugin', 'FormPlugin'],
    },
    'Contact': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['CMSArticlePlugin'],
    },
    'Editions': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['CMSArticlePlugin', 'FormPlugin'],
    },
    'Involved': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['CMSArticlePlugin', 'FormPlugin'],
    },
    'Gallery': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['CMSArticlePlugin', 'FormPlugin'],
    },
    'News': {
        'excluded_plugins': ['FormPlugin'],
    },
}
```

Great job, Django CMS Team!